# How to display conditional placeholder and label dependent upon viewport

Tags: html, css, forms, input, placeholder

I'm so close to figuring this out, but am stuck on a few remaining items. I'm trying to create a text input field that contains a conditional placeholder that works like this:

- At widths under 992px, the label should display above the text input field and the placeholder inside the input should read, 'Enter your make and model.'
- At widths equal to and above 992px, the label above the text input field should be hidden and the placeholder inside the input will have two different styles and should read, '**Check your recall status.** Enter your make and model'.

I've got it mostly working except I can't figure out how to move the label above the input field without breaking the placeholder.

Also, at widths under 484 pixels, the placeholder starts getting cut off despite the input field being wide enough to accommodate the entire placeholder.

I created a Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Codewalker/r624jsdc/

Here's my code, so far:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" />
    <label for="name">Check your recall status. </label>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
input {
    width: 316px;
}
input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
}
input[required] + label {
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    left: -322px;
}

input[required]:invalid + label {
    display: inline;
}

input[required]:valid + label{
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
     input {
       width: 386px;
     }
    input[required] + label {
      color: #999;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      position: relative;
      left: -392px; 
    } 
  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    input {
      width: 501px;
    }
    input[required] + label {
      color: #999;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      position: relative;
      left: -507px; 
    }
    input[required] + label::after {
    content: ' Enter your make and model';
      color: red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adjusting 'top' instead of 'left'?

```css
input {
    width: 316px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
}

input[required]+label {
    display: block;
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    left: 0.5em;
    top: -1.4em;
}

input[required]:valid+label {
    opacity: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    input {
        width: 386px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    input {
        width: 501px;
    }

    input[required]+label::after {
        content: ' Enter your make and model';
        color: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>At widths under 992px, the label should display above the text input field and the placeholder inside the input should read 'Enter your make and model.'</li>
    <li>At widths equal to and above 992px, the label above the text input field should be hidden and the placeholder inside the input will have two different styles and should read '<b>Check your recall status.</b> Enter your make and model'.</li>
</ul>
<br>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required">
    <label for="name">Check your recall status.</label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try, but it didn't work.

Comment: @linnse I changed it to a snippet and it seems to work on StackOverflow. Am I missing something?